# Erro de teste - Chai/Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, testes-de-unidade, mocha

Olá!
Estou estudando sobre testes unitários com Chai e Mocha.
Nunca mexi com isso antes, mas agora estou sentindo a necessidade de aprender sobre.
Tenho o seguinte código:

```
module.exports = {
//Create - Method POST
async storeNewUser(request, response) {
    const { name, email, password } = request.body;
    const passwordEncripted = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    const user = await User.findOrCreate({
        where: {
            email
        }, 
        defaults: { name, password: passwordEncripted }
    }).spread((userResult, created) => {
        if (created) {
            const token = generateNewToken(userResult.id);
            userResult.password = undefined;
            return response.status(201).json({ userResult, token });
        }
        return response.status(400).json({message: "User already exists."});
    });
},
```

Criei o seguinte teste para a função storeNewUser()

```
const chai = require('chai');
const http = require('chai-http');
const subset = require('chai-subset');

const User = require('../src/app/controllers/User');

chai.use(http);
chai.use(subset);

const userSchema = {
    userResult: {
        name: name => name,
        email: email => email,
        password: password => password
    },
    token: {
        token: token => token
    }
};

describe('Integration test', () => {
    it ('/users - POST', () => {
        chai.request(User.storeNewUser).post('/users').send({
            name: "Nome do Usuario",
            email: "email@exemplo.com",
            password: "54321"
        }).end((err, res) => {
            chai.expect(err).to.be.null;
            chai.expect(res).to.have.status(201);
            chai.expect(res.body).to.containSubset([userSchema]);
        });
    });
});
```

Quando eu rodo o teste aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é meu arquivo index.js onde crio a aplicação e chamo o `app.use(express.json())`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = 3000;

require('./database');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(require('./routes'));

// These routes require authentication
app.use(require('./auth-routes'));

app.listen(PORT, console.log('Server running on port '+ PORT));
```

Este é meu arquivo de rotas routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const userController = require('./app/controllers/User');
const authController = require('./app/controllers/Auth');

router.post('/login', authController.login);
router.post('/users', userController.storeNewUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Alguém tem ideia de onde é que eu estou errando?

Comment: Coloca código pf e não imagens de código... Não vejo `request.body` em lugar nenhum. Tens a certeza que estás a mostrar o código certo?

Comment: request.body está na linha 4 do primeiro bloco de código. Fiz uma desestruturação.

Comment: Esse `chai.request(User.storeNewUser)` implementa o `body` no `request`? No Node tens o body-parser que faz isso no Express por exemplo... pode ser esse o problema, que ele esteja a criar um mock diferente do que tens na aplicação.

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo routes.js que chama a funcao que eu estou querendo testar.

Comment: `router.post('/users', userController.storeNewUser);`

Comment: Sim isso eu percebo, e no Express estás a usar o `body-parser` ou `app.use(express.json())`?

Comment: `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: Veja [esse trecho do README do `chai-http` (no _npm_)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-http#caveat). Quando usar o `.end()`, acaba se tornando necessário receber a função `done` (como parâmetro da _callback_ do `it()`), para poder sinalizar quando o teste realmente tiver sido concluído.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o problema!

Eu estava chamando a função que eu quero testar quando eu escrevi:

```
chai.request(User.storeNewUser).post('/users').send({
```

O correto é eu chamar a aplicação como agora:

```
const app = require('../src/index');

chai.request(app).post('/users').send({
```

Obrigado Sergio e Gustavo Sampaio pela ajuda.